# Web part error on Team Foundation Server Project Portal Sharepoint site

Tags: tfs, wss-3.0

I recently installed TFS 2010 with the included sharepoint services on a single server.

I am getting the following error multiple times on the project dashboard web page on the TFS2010 project protal after creating a brand new project in the default project collection. I am not an expert with WSS, so any guidance will be greatly appreciated. After reading a few articles I understand there are some DLL that are probably not declared as safe in a web config file. But I am not sure which DLL they are and where the web config file is. I looked at IIS to determine the directory structure in IIS is quiet different to the URL path ...Thanks very much.

**Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type is not registered as safe.**

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in TFS 2010, and to resolve it, I had to...

1) Change the SharePoint Web Application URL in Team Foundation Server Administration Console, Application Tier, SharePoint Web Applications.  It originally did not have the ending "/", so I added it.  (This may or may not have mattered.)

2) In SharePoint Central Administration (CA), retract the TFS solutions, starting at the bottom of the list.  Wait for the solutions to be retracted.

3) Still in CA, re-deploy the TFS solutions, starting at the top of the list.

4) Back in TFS Administration Console, Application Tier, SharePoint Web Applications, select the web application and Repair Connection.

To see where in CA to find the TFS solutions, see "Verifying the Team Foundation Solutions have been deployed" in the Troubleshooting Guide, linked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/4acefd21-725d-4107-ba9c-bdfa8fe54012).

I don't know what caused this problem to begin with.  It was possibly the missing "/" on the SharePoint web application name, or perhaps changing TFS to use SSL after completing the configuration wizard.

This is a test environment, and I'm not a TFS expert.  This worked for me, but I don't know what the implications of retracting and re-deploying the SharePoint solutions are.

Mary

Answer (score 0):

Try "Repair Connection" on the relevant Sharepoint Application in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you already had a working TFS system and this suddenly started occuring to your webparts...

- Goto Operations Tab.
- Click on Solution Managment
- Ensure `tswawebpartcollection.wsp` is Deployed. If not, click on it and then deploy it.
- Then, to goto Application Mgmt tab.
- Click on Manage "Web application features"
- Activate any TFS items that are not active.

Not sure how this solution ever became undeployed on its own, but this fixed it for me.